# Angular 8 Flex Layout is not hiding mat toolbar options when side navbar appeared on mobile screen

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-flex-layout

I am having 2 errors in the following html script related to `angular`, `angular material` and `flex-layout` project:

```
 <div class="main-bar">
  <mat-sidenav-container  class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false" color="primary"
      fxLayout="column" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()"
          *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
          <mat-icon  aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <div class="flex-items">
          <div>
            <img class="logo" src="../../assets/logo.png">
          </div>
          <div fxHide.gt-md="false">
            <a mat-list-item>Home</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-toolbar>
    </mat-sidenav-content>

  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

The very first problem is when the screen is small, or at least opened on a mobile/tab device, the `Home` and other page buttons at the toolbar should be disappeared to be replaced inside `sidenav`. Which it's not happening.

[image]

I am using `<mat-sidenav fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center"` to get the `menu` icon to the end of the toolbar, and it's not working either.

The second error is that the menu icon appears with a background behind it as you can see at the image above.

I am using `fxHide.gt-sm="true"` to only show `sidenav` on mobile which is working but others are not.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vkkhs).